# My visual studio 10,11 not working?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express

I am using VS10 , Vwd11 beta in my computer both. None of them are working fine. When I run the software I got different kind of problems.

1. when I run VS express 11 it's goes crash when I debug them I got error that

   Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
2. When I run v10 and install any plugins it's give me same error. Same error I got when I run SQL server 2008 r2 in my system.

I  am unable to use none of them.Can someone guideline me if It's can be solved.

Answer (score 2):

These problems are consistent with a bad case of registry corruption.  Particularly the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}\ProxyStubClsid32 value, it declares the proxy/stub that's required to marshal the interface.  The CLSID there could be messed up as well.  Or the security attributes for the key.  This kind of problem will indeed be wide-spread, IServiceProvider is a very common interface in Microsoft code.  Running SysInternals' ProcMon should help to confirm this diagnostic.

You can try to repair it from a .reg file you create on a good machine but this kind of damage is rarely limited to just one key.  At least a repair or reinstall of the components should be contemplated first.  Which isn't that likely to work btw, I imagine you installed VS11 pretty recently.  Uninstall any "registry cleaner" type of program from your machine.  Ask more questions about registry health at superuser.com

Comment: I have tried to find ProxyStubClsid32  but it's not found in Interface{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}. @hans, can you fixit on my computer that i am able to give you more detailed.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what the exception is telling you.  Sorry, I only fix my mom's machine.  Maybe you can find a volunteer at superuser.